# Making a regex in JavaScript to find the "action" attribute in the form tag and replace it

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am currently making a HTML form upload system. I am trying to read the HTML file using `fs.readFile` then I'm attempting to replace the action attribute of the form tag with `"/form/" + form._id`, so that the form makes POST requests to this route.

I am having trouble making a regex to find the action attribute. This is what I have until now:

```
var newData = data.replace(/action(? *)=(? *)("|')(?=.*)("|')/g, 'action="/form/' + form._id + '/");
```

I know the regex is wrong. I really couldn't understand how it works. If you have an answer please write and explanation too if you don't mind. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you try to read the HTML file and why are you reading the HTML file? To get the action of a form loaded into a page or into a container, do `container.querySelector("form").getAtttribute("action")`, where container could be `document` if there is one in the platform you are using

Comment: Sorry mplungjan I forgot to clarify that I'm using node.js.

Comment: I suspected as much. You do have a node Dom parser though

Comment: mplungjan could you elaborate? That could be very helpful.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser - I do not know if it is useful - I do not do node

Comment: This package is only used for parsing. I cannot change the HTML.

Comment: careful not to [summon Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8031815).

Comment: You use a domparser to parse HTML - feed the form to the parser and you can get the action without regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for any attribute before and after the action attribute. It also makes sure the replace only happens in a form tag.

```js
var form = {
  _id: 123
};
var path = '/test/' + form._id;
var str = '<form method="post" action="/test/1" class="foo"></form>';

var result = str.replace(/(<form [^>]*? action=["'])([^"']*)/, '$1' + path);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need such complex regex for that

```js
const path = "/form/1";

const str = `<form action="/test/1" method="POST" data-id="420"></form>`;

const result1 = str.replace(/action=\"(.*?)\"/gm, `action="${path}"`);
const result2 = str.replace(/(?<=action=\")(.*?)(?=\")/gm, path); // with positive lookbehind,lookahead


console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: this is great but if there is any other attribute like method in the form (which is crucial to the function of the form) it will remove it. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Updated answer. Turned regex to non greedy